# How to have transparency in frames, but disable transparency in PDF windows?

Tags: window, frames, pdf

Basically what the title said.
I like to have some transparency. (got it with following line)

```elisp
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 95 95))
```

However, this makes PDF buffers also transparent, which makes it harder to read the PDF.

How to disable transparency on PDF (or DocView) window/frames?

Comment: `alpha` is a *frame* parameter, so maybe the only way is to display your PDF in another *frame*.

Comment: https://kristofferbalintona.me/posts/202206071000/